# Spatstat, using the Matérn cluster process to generate homogeneous landscapes, how do I interpret the Ripley K function?

Tags: r, statistics, spatstat

I am looking to develop a point process that ranges from homogeneous, i.e. no correlation between points to a point cluster process that does have correlation between points. From experimentation I can see that using the Matérn cluster process I can generate landscapes that are clustered.

```
library(spatstat)
plot(rMatClust(kappa=3,r=0.1,mu=50))
```

[image]

I want to use the simplest code that increases the level of homogeneity, i.e. decreasing dependence of points on each other. I do not want to use a binary model where either the pattern is homogeneous or not. i.e. Just a poisson process which can be generated such as:

```
plot(rpoispp(150))
```

[image]

From experimentation I noticed that if I increase the radius of the clusters using the Matérn cluster process, I do seem to create a pseudo homogeneous pattern.

```
plot(rMatClust(kappa=3,r=0.3,mu=50))
```

[image]

```
plot(rMatClust(kappa=3,r=0.7,mu=50))
```

[image]

Is this a good way of generating degrees of homogeneity? I understand that I can use statistical tests to measure the degree of clustering compared to a complete poisson process, such as the Ripley K test. For example, if I assign the Matérn cluster process data to variables, such as:

```
a<-rMatClust(kappa=3,r=0.1,mu=50)
b<-rMatClust(kappa=3,r=0.3,mu=50)
c<-rMatClust(kappa=3,r=0.7,mu=50)
```

Then use the Ripley K test and plot the results:

```
plot(Kest(a))
```

[image]

```
plot(Kest(b))
```

[image]

```
plot(Kest(c))
```

[image]

I can see that the difference between a homogeneous poisson process and the clustered point process decreases. I still do not fully understand the significance of the various K values according to edge effects and so forth, and how to interpret the Ripley K function, but I think this is the right direction to be heading in? How do I interpret the Ripley K function? Another problem is the number of points in each plot, I do not have a consistent number of points in each plot, as can be seen by:

```
summary(a)
summary(b)
summary(c)
```

Any knowledgeable feedback on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The standard terminology is that you want to generate a **clustered** point pattern.

The function `rMatClust` generates a clustered point pattern at random, in a two-stage process. The first stage is to generate "parent" points completely at random. The second stage is to generate, for each "parent", a random number of "offspring" points, and to place the "offspring" points inside a circle of radius `R` around their "parent". The final result is the collection of all "offspring" points. From this description (and `help(rMatClust)`) you can figure out what happens for different parameter values.

The `K` function (not the "K test") is a summary of the spacing between points in a point pattern. At a distance `r`, the value of `K(r)` is the normalised average number of points observed to fall within distance `r` of a typical point in the pattern. It is normalised so that it does not depend on the number of points, making it possible to compare patterns with different numbers of points.

When you plot the `K` function, one of the curves is the theoretical curve that would be expected if the points are completely random, and the other curves are computed from the data point pattern. This allows you to assess whether the point pattern appears to be clustered.

I strongly suggest you do some reading in Chapter 7 of [the spatstat book](http://book.spatstat.org). You can download this chapter for free.

Comment: Many thanks, this is a very clear explanation, I did not realise that the K function was normalised. I am very new to spatial statistics so I will definitely read the recommended chapter.